# How do you move the cursor to the next element in a contenteditable div in Chrome/Safari?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, cursor-position

I have logic to insert a  tag in a contenteditable div. I want to set the cursor to the start of the following element after the insertion. The code I have to do this is:

```
function insertNodeAtCaret(node) {
if(typeof window.getSelection !== 'undefined')
{
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if(sel.rangeCount)
    {
        var rng = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        rng.collapse(false);
        rng.insertNode(node);

        // The following doesn't work in Chrome or Safari
        node = node.nextSibling;
        rng.setEndAfter(node);
        rng.setStartAfter(node);
        rng.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(rng);
    }
}
else if (typeof document.selection !== 'undefined' && document.selection.type !== 'Control')
{
    document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(node.outerHTML);
}
}
```

However though this works perfectly in IE, Opera and Firefox it doesn't work in Chrome and Safari. In Chrome/Safari the cursor is placed at the end of the text within the span, rather than after the span. ie

```
<span>text CURSOR HERE</span>
```

instead of what I am wanting, which is:

```
<span>text</span>CURSOR HERE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [long-standing and annoying bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23189). See also [the bug for the special case of placing the caret inside an empty inline element](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15256), which has more activity. There's not a lot you can do about it, unless inserting and selecting a single zero-width space character is acceptable.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I had to work on a few other items. Just wanted to say a big thanks to Tim for your input, much appreciated. Frustrating that some of these issues have been around for years with no resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `contentEditable={false}` to the element you inserted :

```
<div contentEditable={true}> 
   <span contenEditable={false>/span>
</div>
```