# Contenteditable div set caret after replacing text with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to make a web-based code editor, and I came up with a way to sweep the entire text and replace anything that matches my super simple regex to colored HTML. See it here:

```
$("#text-area").on('keyup', function(e){
    var html = $("#text-area").html();
    var filter = html.replace(/function/g, '<span style="color:pink;">function</span>');
    $("#text-area").html(filter);
});
```

I spent hours digging stackoverflow and found similar situations, but subtly different that I can't apply to my situation here. Here is the problem:

1) Once I sweep the text and replace selective words to colored HTML, the caret is returned to the beginning of the div.

2) Since it is a code-editor(reading other files), I need white-space: `pre` or `pre-wrap`. But then caret positions are the same for any number of line breaks, so the caret doesn't move and new lines are just added below the caret, and from any new empty line it jumps up to whichever line isn't empty.

I have the simplified version of my situation in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davy123/53u4nozy/)

Comment: Why are you using the HTML5-only `contenteditable` attribute instead of a simple `<input type="text">` or `<textarea>`?

Comment: As far as I know, I can't change the text of individual words in a 'text-area' because it only deals with words. 'content-editable' can use HTML for styling

Comment: [Something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351714)

Answer (score 0):

There is better ways but this is the close solution I got to yours.

Have something have something like when you detect the word you like:

```
<div> 
      <span class="normal_text"> First part </span> 
      <span style="color:pink;">function</span>
      <span class="normal_text"> | </span>
</div>
```

And in the end put the [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) equal to [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange) with offset 0 and focus node as the last span. Your function looking for the word "function" should also be listening the last span only to repeat everything.